# Print Strings instead of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have a beginner question about generating Fibonacci numbers in Java.

In this java program, the method should print Fibonnacci numbers sequence from `BeginIndex` to `LastIndex`, so it should print `"Hi"` (instead of number) if the number is a multiple of 5, print `"I am"` if the number is a multiple of 7 and print `"Hi I am me"` if the number is a multiple of 35. I am not really sure on how to do this.

```
class FibonacciClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        generatefibonacci(10, 20);
        generatefibonacci(0, 1);


    }


      private static void generatefibonacci(int BeginIndex, int LastIndex) {



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
private static void generateFibonacci(int beginIndex, int lastIndex) {

    int len = lastIndex + 1;
    int[] fib = new int[len];
    fib[0] = 0; 
    fib[1] = 1;

    // Building Fibonacci sequence from beginIndex through lastIndex
    for (int i = 2; i < len; ++i)
        fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];

    // Printing 
    for (int index = beginIndex; index <= lastIndex; ++index) {

        if ((fib[index] % 5 == 0) && (fib[index] % 7 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("Hi I am me");
        }
        else if (fib[index] % 5 == 0) { 
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
        else if (fib[index] % 7 == 0) {
            System.out.println("I am");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(fib[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you should test `if (fib[index] % 5 == 0)` instead of if the index. Also you could test for the first case `if (fib[index] % 35 == 0)` instead of testing both 7 and 5, but thats just a small optimization.

Comment: yes I would correct your post. I think that he wants to know if the fibonacci number is divisible by 5 or 7, not if the index is divisble by 5 or 7. That is my assumption, otherwise your answer looks good.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the modulus operator, %. It will return the remainder of division by its operands. So, receiving a true value from if (x % 5 == 0 && x % 7 == 0) would represent the number x being both multiples of 5 and 7. If this case does not pass, you should use else if statements to individually check for if x is a multiple of 5 and then another for if x is a multiple of 7, with each if branch calling System.out.println("x is a multiple of y");

Answer (score 0):

Everytime **generatefibonacci** has produced a result you have to check with modulo (%).

Like this:

```
private static generatefibonnacci(int startIndex, int endIndex){
int result = -1;
//do generating stuff
//and set "result" to generated fibonacci
//and then
if(result%5==0){
    System.out.println("Hi");
} else if(result%7==0){
    System.out.println("Hi I am me!");
} //and so on
```

So this is just a little example.
Have fun

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static void generatefibonacci(int BeginIndex, int LastIndex) {
     int[] numbers = new int[LastIndex + 2]; //creates an array to put fibonacci numbers in
     numbers[0] = 1; numbers[1] = 1;
     for(int i = 2; i <= LastIndex; i ++){
         numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1] + numbers[i - 2]; //generates the Fibonacci Sequence
     }
     for(int i = BeginIndex; i <= LastIndex; i ++){
         if(numbers[i] % 5 == 0 && numbers[i] % 7 == 0){//if the remainder when the numbers/5 equals 0 and the remainder when the numbers/7 equals 0
             System.out.println("Hello I am me");
         }
         else if(numbers[i] % 5 == 0){ //if the remainder when the numbers/5 equals 0
             System.out.println("I am");
         }
         else if(numbers[i] % 7 == 0){ //if the remainder when the numbers/7 equals 0
             System.out.println("Hi");
         }
         else{ //if none of the above three conditions are true
             System.out.println(numbers[i]);
         }
     }

 }
```